# Convert a input checkbox to 2 separate buttons

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

The input checkbox toggles between light/dark mode. However, I want it as 2 separate buttons. How do I go about this?

**Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/ot1ecnxz/1**

HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" role="switch" id="flexSwitchCheckChecked" checked onclick="myFunction()" />
<hr />
<button type="button" data-bs-theme-value="light"> Light </button>
<button type="button" data-bs-theme-value="dark"> Dark </button>
<hr />
<p>
This is a sample text
</p>
```

JS:

```
function myFunction() {
    var element = document.body;
  element.dataset.bsTheme =
  element.dataset.bsTheme == "dark" ? "light" : "dark";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If checkbox replaced by 2 dedicated buttons code to achieve this should be,

HTML :

```html
<button type="button" data-bs-theme-value="light" onclick="setTheme('light')"> Light </button>
<button type="button" data-bs-theme-value="dark" onclick="setTheme('dark')"> Dark </button>
<hr />
<p>
    This is a sample text
</p>
```

Javascript:

```js
function setTheme(theme) {
    document.body.dataset.bsTheme = theme;
}
```

Comment: Much cleaner way to go about it. Thank you. Accepted as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

**Html**

```
<button type="button" onclick="setTheme('light')">Light</button>
<button type="button" onclick="setTheme('dark')">Dark</button>
```

**JS**

```
function setTheme(theme) {
   var element = document.body;
   element.dataset.bsTheme = theme;
}
```

**try for this code**