# Use buttons to choose colors instead of a checkbox switch

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

I tried various methods to use button instead of the existing checkbox but couldn't get it to work. I tried the onClick method too but failed as well.

**DEMO: https://jsfiddle.net/yxez4a2u/**

HTML:

```
<div class="form-check form-switch">
  <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="darkModeSwitch" checked>
  <label class="form-check-label" for="darkModeSwitch">Dark Mode</label>
</div>

<button type="button" onclick="darkModeSwitch('light')"> Light </button>
<button type="button" onclick="darkModeSwitch('dark')"> Dark </button>

<p>
This is a Bootstrap 5 color mode with storage functionality
</p>
```

JS:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
    const htmlElement = document.documentElement;
    const switchElement = document.getElementById('darkModeSwitch');

    // Set the default theme to dark if no setting is found in local storage
    const currentTheme = localStorage.getItem('bsTheme') || 'light';
    htmlElement.setAttribute('data-bs-theme', currentTheme);
    switchElement.checked = currentTheme === 'light';

    switchElement.addEventListener('change', function () {
        if (this.checked) {
            htmlElement.setAttribute('data-bs-theme', 'light');
            localStorage.setItem('bsTheme', 'light');
        } else {
            htmlElement.setAttribute('data-bs-theme', 'dark');
            localStorage.setItem('bsTheme', 'dark');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: In your html, what behavior do you expect from this part `darkModeSwitch="light"` etc?

Comment: @GetSet Behavior as in? I would like to remove the checkbox toggle and use 2 separate buttons instead. Something along the lines of `onclick` may be. I'm unable to get it to work.

Comment: You wrote `darkModeSwitch="light"` on your button tag for a reason. I'm asking why?

Comment: _"I'm unable to get it to work."_ - can you show us your _attempt_ at least then, please.

Comment: I don't see anywhere in your code, where is your logic for the 2 buttons, they serve no purpose right now

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert a input checkbox to 2 separate buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78198793/convert-a-input-checkbox-to-2-separate-buttons) - Please **don't** open multiple identical questions. That is **not** going to get you a quicker answer.

Comment: your question already had an accepted answer... why are you asking the same thing again?

Comment: @ChrisG Because that answer has a different JS code and doesn't have local storage. Hence, this new question. I'm sorry for the confusion.

Comment: There is no confusion. Just don't open the SAME question multiple times. And please read [ask]. *It doesn't work* and *it failed* are **not** proper problem descriptions. Please create a [mcve] that allows to reproduce the issue, along with a clear problem description and debugging details. With almost 4K reputation, you should be **well aware** of that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After adding IDs to the button elements, You can select them. Then with an event listener to each button, giving them a click function. Each button triggers the setTheme function with different arguments. After that, it sets the theme to localStorage.

```
<div class="form-check form-switch">
  <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="darkModeSwitch" checked>
  <label class="form-check-label" for="darkModeSwitch">Dark Mode</label>
</div>

<button type="button" id="lightModeButton"> Light </button>
<button type="button" id="darkModeButton"> Dark </button>

<p>
This is a Bootstrap 5 color mode with storage functionality
</p>

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
const htmlElement = document.documentElement;
const switchElement = document.getElementById('darkModeSwitch');
const lightModeButton = document.getElementById('lightModeButton');
const darkModeButton = document.getElementById('darkModeButton');

const currentTheme = localStorage.getItem('bsTheme') || 'light';
htmlElement.setAttribute('data-bs-theme', currentTheme);
switchElement.checked = currentTheme === 'light';

function setTheme(theme) {
    htmlElement.setAttribute('data-bs-theme', theme);
    localStorage.setItem('bsTheme', theme);
    switchElement.checked = theme === 'light';
}

switchElement.addEventListener('change', function () {
    setTheme(this.checked ? 'light' : 'dark');
});

lightModeButton.addEventListener('click', function () {
    setTheme('light');
});

darkModeButton.addEventListener('click', function () {
    setTheme('dark');
});
});
```

Comment: I upvoted too. However, I'm getting this error: 
`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of null (setting 'checked')` on the line no: `switchElement.checked = currentTheme === 'light';`

Comment: You can check here, same code. You will see that it works.
https://jsfiddle.net/emreesrc/rsLop5wn/

Comment: It certainly does.

Comment: @Emre Thank you but I have to replace the input checkbox and that's when the error occurs: https://jsfiddle.net/0oxz9bvu/

Comment: @GetSet Please see this updated code after removing the input checkbox: https://jsfiddle.net/0oxz9bvu/

Comment: @ElaineByene Thats because you removed the element from the html but you didnt remove the javascript that assumes it exists. Follow the js line by line to understand what it does. Dont simply copy and paste snippets when they are relatively trivial. Try and understand them too.

Comment: @ElaineByene Please remove all switchElement related code. Line 3, 9, 14, 17,18,19